# Download Audio file like Gaana Android app

Tags: android, download, audio-streaming

I have created an Android Application, in that I am playing and downloading audio file from server. So when user download audio file from server he/she can't show that file in File Manager or any other media player like [Gaana](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gaana&hl=en) app.

How to make it possible?

Thanks,

Sagar.

Comment: I really not going to see how Gaana app works, but I want to help you. So pls confirm that I understood your question correctly: You want to download and play audio files with your own app, but you don't want other apps to see this files, right?

Comment: @VladMatvienko, Yes, Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the files in **Internal Storage Area.** These **files would be private to your app only.**
Using **getFilesDir()** on any context provides absolute path to the filesystem directory where your internal files are saved. There in you can create directory. For more information refer [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use few approaches:

1. Download files into the private application's directory. No other apps will have access to those files. Pros of this approach is that is is the easiest way. Cons is that the inner storage might be limited in the device.
2. Download files saving them with incorrect file extensions. Pros: easy to implement, can save anywhere. Cons: files can be accessed, copied and renamed by any other app.
3. The same way as 2nd approach, but add some encryption to the files, so nobody except you can use them. This approach might require on-the-fly decryption.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try using first option.

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko Have a example or demo of 1st and 3rd approach ?